# Flex 4 (Air) - ShowDialog-like behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

The ShowDialog function in VB.NET allows a child window (form) to be opened in front of another without letting the user interact with the parent window until the child is closed.

To see what I'm referring to (in Windows), open up notepad, click help > about, and then click back on the main window. You'll notice that the dialog flashes and makes a noise. That happens with dialogs in a great many applications, and that is what I'm trying to achieve.

I can't seem to find any way to replicate this in Flex 4 (Air) applications. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**

Based on your comment, you then have to create a **new window component**(mxml component with the functionality and interface you want defined in it) and can then attach it to the click event of the link/button on the main window. And for the focus issue you can use [setFocus](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/FocusManager.html#setFocus%28%29) from IFocusManager component

Comment: Neither are what I'm looking for. The child should be the only thing that the user can interact with until it is closed. However, TitleWindows are not true windows; they are simply panels inside the existing WindowedApplication. My child window is far larger than the main window, and neither should be resized. Again, I want the same functionality as windowName.open() without allowing the user to interact with the main window until the child has been closed. In VB.NET, this would simply be the difference of formName.Show() and formName.ShowDialog()

Comment: check the edited answer above, it should work according to your requirement

Comment: To see what I mean (in Windows), open up notepad, click help > about, and then click back on the main window. You'll notice that the dialog flashes and makes a noise. That happens with dialogs in a huge number of applications, and that is what I'm trying to achieve. Opening a window is easy, and setting focus isn't really needed here.